# Model start time imported from database

Tags: anylogic

I have an excel sheet that import data into my anylogic model database. Is there any way to have the simulation start time to be coded to look at what day/time is in the database to start the simulation. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the internal AnyLogic database you can just retrieve it during *initial experiment setup* and use it to modify the model start date with the following code:

```
getExperiment().getEngine().setStartDate(selectFrom(mytable).firstResult(mytable.mycolumn));
```

[image: Code to retrieve date valuie from internal DB]

Here is an example of the date value stored in the internal database, that fits to the code above:

[image: Database table that contains date value]

The only thing to look out for might be the order of initialization. It might be that the query for the date form the internal database happens **before** the internal database is automatically updated from the Excel file. In this case you should directly query from the Excel file, not from the internal database.

Comment: How can we change just time, with the date. without using database?