# Start a simulation with current time as model time

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where I need to display the date and time coherent with the current ones.
When I try to set the simulation parameters I have to specify each time the start time to a fixed value.
Is there any way to change the start time, even via code?
Thanks a lot,
P

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
[Model start time imported from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015060/model-start-time-imported-from-database?rq=1)

to retrieve the local time I used:

'import java.time.LocalDateTime;
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();'